# Outputting a different table based on a query output using an ID in php

Tags: php, sql-server, loops, sqlsrv

I am trying to output a result under each "result" in PPH based on the result ID using PHP and MSSQL.
I have searched online and tried my best to output the result but the current code shows the result after the whole record.

This selects all the persons from a table and loop through them, then output each color that's related to the person under the Person BEFORE THE NEXT PERSON

Currently, the code outputs the color after listing all the persons.

```
<?php
$tsql = "SELECT * from dbo.dim_person";

$getResults_sbu_l = sqlsrv_query($conn_d, $tsql);

while ($person = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults_sbu_l,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    $arraySbu[$person['Person_id']] = $person;
}

$tsql_acc = "SELECT * from dbo.dim_color";

$getResults_sbu_acc = sqlsrv_query($conn_d, $tsql_acc);

while ($color = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults_sbu_acc,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    $arraySbu[$color['Person_id']]['color_id'][] = $color;
}

foreach($arraySbu AS $person)
{
    echo  $person['person_name'] . "<br>";

    foreach($person['color_id'] AS $color)
    {
        echo $color['color_name'] . "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where does `$staff['color_name']` come from? Probably it's `$color['color_name']`. And can you post the definitions for the `dim_person` and `dim_color` tables?

Comment: yeah. It's `$color['color_name']` . That was a mistake. I will update it. The person table has person_id and person_name. Then the color table has color_id,person_id,color_name

Comment: With this correction, your script should work as you expect. The only problematic situation is when you have a person without colors. In this case the script will generate a warning ` ... Undefined index: color_id in ...`. Can you check your output again? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the next approach may help. It's not necessary to execute two separate statements, store the data in an array and use a loop to output the data stored in this array. You may try to execute a single statement, using the appropriate `JOIN` and `ORDER BY`.

```
<?php
// Statement. 
// Use LEFT (RIGHT) join if you want to include (exclude) persons without colors.
$tsql = "
    SELECT p.person_name, c.color_name 
    FROM  dbo.dim_person p
    LEFT JOIN dbo.dim_color c ON p.person_id = c.person_id 
    ORDER BY p.person_name, c.color_name
";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn_d, $tsql);
if ($result === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

// Results
$person = '';
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($person != $row['person_name']) {
        $person = $row['person_name'];
        echo $row['person_name']."<br>";
    }
    echo $row['color_name']."<br>";
}

// End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);
sqlsrv_close($conn_d);
?>
```